# get bookmarks in agsXMPP

Tags: agsxmpp

i created a xmpp client connections.
i wanna load my xmpp jid bookmarks.

this is server reply to my Get bookmarks request :

```html
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:private"><storage xmlns="storage:bookmarks"><conference autojoin="false" jid="andimeshk@conference.nimbuzz.com" name="andimeshk"><nick>saman</nick></conference><conference autojoin="false" jid="iran@conference.progeron.ru" name="iran@conference.progeron.ru"><nick>saman</nick></conference><conference autojoin="false" jid="python@conference.jabber.ru" name="python@conference.jabber.ru"><nick>saman</nick></conference></storage></query>
```

i wanna select jid value in this tags:

```html
<conference autojoin="false" jid="iran@conference.progeron.ru" name="iran@conference.progeron.ru"><nick>saman</nick></conference>
```

```html
<conference autojoin="false" jid="python@conference.jabber.ru" name="python@conference.jabber.ru"><nick>saman</nick></conference>
```

how can i do it ?